# Angular 2: How to use ng2-translate alongside in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

I'm using ng2-translate for i18n translations + in-memory-web-api for mock data.

Without the in-memory-web-api the i18n translations work as they should but with it enabled angular's Http service cannot resolve the correct path to the translation files because the mock data takes over.

Any way for both of them to work at the same time?

Here's what I have in the app.module.ts

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CoreModule,
        routing,
        CookieModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [Http]
        }),
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(MockDataService),
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a config argument to [handle requests for collections that are not in the in-memory database](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#pass-thru-to-a-live-xhrbackend).

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(MockDataService, { passThruUnknownUrl: true })
```